# How can i solve the problem about TestNG and Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, testng

I am using Testng with mockmvc to unit test the controller of a springboot project;I don't know how to apply Tesng to the springboot project

ExcelDownLoadController::

```
package app.dnatask.controller.download;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/API/download/Excel")
public class ExcelDownLoadController extends BaseController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel/exportResult/test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("http successful.....");
    }
}
```

ExcelDownLoadControllerTest::

```
package app.dnatask.controller.download;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExcelDownLoadController.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "app.dnatask.controller",lazyInit = true)
@WebAppConfiguration()

public class ExcelDownLoadControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforemethod() {
        System.out.println("=====start testing=====");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void aftermethod() {
        System.out.println("=====end testing=====");
    }


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void tedtDemo() throws Exception{

        mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).dispatchOptions(true).build();
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/API/download/Excel/downloadExcel/exportResult/test"))
                                     .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                      .andReturn();
        System.out.println("success coming in Test............");
    }
}
```

Exception::

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'excelDownLoadController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'excelDownLoadRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'app.dnatask.domain.repository.ExcelDownLoadRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'app.dnatask.domain.repository.ExcelDownLoadRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 74 more
```

When the annotation is missing @ContextConfiguration and @ComponentScan, another error is reported (java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>)
This problem does not occur with junit
How can i solve this problem....

Comment: Please try adding @EnableWebMvc annotation to your spring configuration and try again. Hope it helps

Comment: it doesn't work....

Comment: By any chance, why is lazyInit = true marked in ComponentScan

Comment: Because I don't want to load all beans every time I run the test method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason ..Test class and controller class are named in the same package path...
[image]

[image]

The solution is as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ScanResultConfigureController.class})
@ComponentScan(
        includeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
                        value = {ScanResultConfigureController.class})
        },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        lazyInit = true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load the context using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`?. It's similar to the `@ContextConfiguration` but it uses Spring Boot's *SpringApplicationContextLoader* to load/manage the application context. When you use it, you point it to your main Application class.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class ControllerTest {
//....
```

that would ideally be  similar to :

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeConfigClass.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "app.dnatask.controller",lazyInit = true)
@WebAppConfiguration()
```

Btw, for that `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExcelDownLoadController.class)`, `@ContextConfiguration` is used to load/manage the application context (web app context in this case) so it would normally `@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeConfigClass.class)`.